# Как узнать дату последнего смещения тем в Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

У меня есть Kafka множеством топиков.
И есть Consumer Kafka для чтения записей из этих тем:

```
    public Set<ConsumerRecord> consumeKafka() {
        consumer.subscribe(topics);

        Set<ConsumerRecord> resultRecords = new HashSet<>();

        int i = 0;
        while (i++ < topicIteration) {
            ConsumerRecords<Object, Object> records = consumer.poll(100);
            System.out.println(records.partitions());

            for (ConsumerRecord consumerRecord : records){
                resultRecords.add(consumerRecord);
            }
        }
        return resultRecords;
    }

private Consumer consumerInit(String consumerId){
    props = new Properties();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, consumerId);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    if (isActualizationTopics) {
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1);
    } else {
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, topicLimit);
    }

    return new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
}
```

Чтобы не читать все топики подряд, мне нужно отсортировать список топиков, и получать данные из тех, из которых данные не читались дольше всего. Я так понимаю мне нужно получить дату последнего смещения по каждому топику и отсортировать? Как можно это сделать? Или возможно есть другие подходы к решению?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой возможности нет. Кафка работает только с оффсетами и не интересуется датами. Вы можете попробовать решить задачу, сохраняя эту информацию на стороне приложения в формате <топик, дата_последнего_чтения>.

Comment: Может подскажете еще такой вопрос. Я могу получить consumer.endOffsets(topicPartitions). Но как узнать, есть ли новые записи после этого офсета? (нужно пропускать топики у которых нету новых записей для данного консьюмера, поскольку на попытку чтения тратится время)

Comment: @ЛеонидДубравский подпишитесь на получение статистики и смотрите, если ли лаг (это разница между последним оффсетом вообще и последним прочитанным). Пример получения статистики: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/Consumer/Program.cs Небольшая дока по полям здесь: https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/Consumer-lag-monitoring